# How to get 4 bytes of data (uint8_t) into a variable of type uint32_t

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsdata, int32

I've been working with Cypress BLE PSoC 4200, and I've set up my GATT database to send `int32` data packets to my iPhone.  However, you can only write to the GATT database with `uint8` pieces of data.  So I wrote the following to take this `int32` voltage reading and put it into a `uint8` byte array:

```
    // function passes in int32 variable 'result'
    uint8 array[4];
    array[0] = result & 0xFF;
    array[1] = (result >> 8) & 0xFF;
    array[2] = (result >> 16) & 0xFF;
    array[3] = (result >> 24) & 0xFF;
```

So, given that in mind, when that `int32` packet gets sent, I want to be able take each byte, and recombine them somehow into the original int32 value, and print it to the screen (e.g. 456000 will be 0.456 V).

Right now, I obtain the 4 bytes and handle them like such:

```
    NSData* data = [characteristic value];
    const uint8_t *reportData = [data bytes];

    // variable to hold the eventual 32-bit data
    uint32_t voltage = 0;
```

Is there a way to go through each index of `*reportData` and concatenate the bytes?  Any help will do, thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the `getBytes` method of `NSData` ...

Comment: `getBytes:length:` method works great, thanks Martin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this not work?

```
uint32_t v0 = (uint32_t)reportData[0];
uint32_t v1 = (uint32_t)reportData[1] << 8;
uint32_t v2 = (uint32_t)reportData[2] << 16;
uint32_t v3 = (uint32_t)reportData[3] << 24;

uint32_t voltage = v0 | v1 | v2 | v3;
```

Comment: At first I thought the cast of `uint32_t` would only "transfer" the address to `v0`, but I was wrong.  This works very well, thanks!